# How to validate if string corresponds to a valid datetime frequency? (E.g. '1D')

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

To put it short, there are several datetime functionalities in python that let you use a frequency to resample date ranges (e.g. daily, weekly, etc, used in the form of ***ts.resample('1D').apply(np.sum)***), yet I haven't found any mechanism to validate if the string is a valid frequency.

I looked into the documentation, where I found the [Offset Aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases), but still no way to validate it.

I also found a prefix_mapping with the offsets, in (pd.offsets.prefix_mapping), but I imagine to use this prefix_mapping I would have to remove the numerical values from the string (e.g. **'M'** instead of **'3M'**).

I am also unsure if these two correspond to the same data structure.

**TLDR**:

Is there any straight-forward way to validate if a string corresponds to an offset / frequency? How to ensure *freq* is valid?

```
 freq = '2D'
 # TODO Validate freq
 pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/09/2018', freq=freq)
```

Comment: Questions with a snippet of input and expected output get better responses than text explanation.

Comment: Thanks @mohanys. I added it a TLDR to be easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pandas function **to_offset**:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.frequencies.to_offset.html

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
to_offset("5min")
to_offset("1D1H")
to_offset("2W")
to_offset("3X")
```

The final to_offset call will generate the error:

*ValueError: Invalid frequency: 3X*

So, you can just use try/except to validate any given offset alias.

Comment: Thank you, Mark! Been a long time coming, ahah

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions, like:

```
[0-9][DM]
```

`1D` or `2D` or `3M` will conform to the previous regular expression.

Refer [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for more information on regular expressions shipped implementation in Python.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's quite a number of different valid [Offset Aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases). I don't think a regex would fix my problem. Thank you, though.

Comment: I don't get to see the counter example you seem to see. Could you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: For example, 1h23m.

Comment: That's not a counter example. `([0-9]M)?([0-9][Hh])?(([0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])[Mm])?` fits that.

Comment: (In case empty string is valid input).

Comment: If you go to the Offset Aliases, you'll see what I mean. There are countless examples, and to make a regex to check every case would be quite convoluted.

Comment: Someone has to write it, and you have the opportunity to do so. :)